# X509Certificate2 fails to parse on Linux but works on Windows

Tags: c#, linux, .net-core, x509certificate2, .net-standard

Creating a X509Certificate2 instance from a byte array works on Windows but fails on Linux with a "CryptographicException".

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var cert = new X509Certificate2(Cert.CertBytes);
}
```

On Windows: Valid X509Certificate2 instance is created
On Linux: An exception is thrown:

`` {System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Cannot find the 
 original signer.
   at Internal.Cryptography.Pal.PkcsFormatReader.TryReadPkcs7(SafePkcs7Handle pkcs7, Boolean single, ICertificatePal& certPal, List`1& certPals)
   at Internal.Cryptography.Pal.PkcsFormatReader.TryReadPkcs7Der(Byte[] rawData, Boolean single, ICertificatePal& certPal, List`1& certPals)
   at Internal.Cryptography.Pal.CertificatePal.FromBlob(Byte[] rawData, SafePasswordHandle password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate..ctor(Byte[] data)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2..ctor(Byte[] rawData)
   at CertTest.Program.Main(String[] args) in /home/CertTest/Program.cs:line 14} ``

Am I doing something wrong? I assume that a certificate is a certificate, regardless of the OS on which it is parsed.

You find a valid X509 certificate which can be parsed on Windows but not Linux here: https://gist.github.com/secana/9c13f8fa495681f8a30adb5d8754450e

I tried multiple certificates, but none worked on Linux. I don't own a Mac so I couldn't test if it would work there.

Tested with .Net Core 2.0.2
on Ubuntu 16.04, Ubuntu 17.10, OpenSuse Tumbleweed, Windows 10

Comment: Issue link: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/25828

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `new X509Certficate2()` does not return the signing certificate under Linux like it does under Windows you have to parse the ASN.1 structure of the PKCS7 to find the signing certificate.

Example:

```
 // Import all certificates in the structure into a collection
 var collection = new X509Certificate2Collection();
 collection.Import(Cert.CertBytes);

 // Find the signing cert
 var signingCert = collection.Cast<X509Certificate2>().FirstOrDefault(cert => 
 string.Equals(cert.SerialNumber, SignerSerialNumber, 
 StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
```

The only difficulty is to get the serial number of the signing cert. For that I've parsed the ASN.1 structure. The serial number is in the ASN.1 path `1/0/4/0/1/1`.

Example:

```
// Get signing cert serial number from ASN.1
var serialNumber = asn1[1][0][4][0][1][1];
```

As an ASN.1 parser I've used code from the Mono project, but there are several parser available on Nuget.

Comment: For those who do not want to jump through the loops I had to, this project (disclaimer: it's mine) implements the solution above. https://github.com/secana/PeNet

Answer (score 4):

It is not an X509 certificate but some signed data (PKCS#7 format). Windows can export certificate in PKCS#7 format with other certificates in the certificate path. That is most likely your case. Try to rename it to p7b and open it in windows. 
[image: ASN.1 representation of binary data]

There are two certificates in the PKCS#7:

- CN=Microsoft Windows, Serial number: 330000016143159d469b7f968b000000000161, issued by Microsoft Windows Production PCA 2011 
  [image: Signing certificate]
- CN=Microsoft Windows Production PCA 2011, Serial number: 61077656000000000008, issued by Microsoft Root Certificate Authority 2010
  [image: SubCA that issued the signing certificate]

The PKCS#7 is signed with timestamp from Microsoft Time-Stamp PCA 2010.

Why does it work on windows but not on linux I don't know. File an issue [here](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues) or try to debug it.

Comment: Thx for the tip with the PKCS#7 parser. I got it working now!